# How to "break" this PRF scheme?

Tags: pseudo-random-function

I'm new to cryptography, and I'm working on exercises that involve "breaking" PRF schemes which involves writing a poly-time program that distinguishes between two particular programs, the ideal random world and the fake random world. Basically, I need to write a poly-time program that "wins" a distinguishing game by determining if an input function is truly random or indeed a PRF.

These are the following conditions for the scheme:

- Let $F: \{0, 1\}^\lambda \times \{0, 1\}^\lambda \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^\lambda$ be a PRF.
- Let $halves$ be a black-box program that splits a string at its middle.
- Given two strings $x$ and $y$:

  - Let $x \oplus y$ represent the bitwise XOR of the two strings

Break the following "PRF" that takes $2 * \lambda$ bits, splits them in half, runs $F$ on each half, then bitwise XORs the result:

```
badPRF(k: {0, 1}^λ, x: {0, 1}^(2λ)):
   x0, x1 = halves(x);
   return F(k, x0) ⊕ F(k, x1);
```

How would I come up with a distinguisher program to prove that the above program is a bad PRF? I'm so confused on how we're supposed to distinguish this as a bad PRF. I have received hints saying that we will have to pass in multiple inputs into badPRF (in clever ways so you can tell how to distinguish between worlds). In other words, pass in many different $x$ and get many different $F(k, x)$ back. But what kind of clever ways should I be using the outputs of the badPRF? Are there any other hints that anyone has regarding how I should write a distinguisher program? I'm not sure where to start with coming up with a distinguisher.

Comment: Hint: What does happen if you send $aa$?

Comment: Picture yourself facing a problem: you have two boxes, one does badPRF, the other is a good PRF. How do you recognize them ? kelalaka's hint will help. Typographical note: The usual notation for bitwise XOR is $\oplus$ (written `\oplus`) when in LaTex/Mathjax. $\wedge$ is usually conjunction, aka AND. In the circumstance, you could use return `F(k, x0) ⊕ F(k, x1);` in the last line of the definition.